# Pad counter with leading 0 up to 9, then remove leading zero with php

Tags: php, count, printf

Trrying to pad with leading 0's up to 9, then remove.

01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 - 10, 11, 12, 14

So far I have this:

```
<?php  $value = $count++;
printf("%02d", $value);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is correct, although you might want to use a loop unless you like copy pasting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use [`str_pad()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
<?php  
    $value = $count++;
    echo str_pad($value, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```