# Manipulate trading value dollar & cent

Tags: php

```
<input name="dollar"...
<input name="cent"...

<?PHP

if ( !is_numeric($_POST['dollar'])) { return; }
if ( !is_numeric($_POST['cent'])) { return; }

$total = $_POST['dollar'].".".$_POST['cent'];
```

I have a trading page, value contain dollar & cent

What I did is check number first and merge dollar & cent together.

It works fine but last night I notice some trading value are incorrect

ex.

user enter 203.06

but my log shows 2030.6

is that possible hacker manipulate dollar & cent like above 2030.6

Comment: why can't a user just put in 2030 for $_POST['dollar'] and 6 for $_POST['cent'] ?

Comment: than my log will show 2030.06 not 2030.6

Comment: dont worry about return, it just stop script and return error message back to view

Comment: seems like a job for http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad counter with leading 0 up to 9, then remove leading zero with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424048/pad-counter-with-leading-0-up-to-9-then-remove-leading-zero-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's limit values user may enter + use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function to print result properly.

```
<input name="dollar"...
<input name="cent"...

<?php
  //Dollar is an integer above zero
  $dollar = max(0, intval($_POST['dollar'])); 

  //Cent is an integer between 0 and 99
  $cent = min(99, max(0, intval($_POST['cent']))); 

  //Version to place into logs
  $total = $dollar.".".$cent;

  // Added from another answer to keep everything together

  //Set the local to parse monetary values correctly
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US");

  //Get correct monetary value with 2 decimal place and **$** sign
  //Version to print
  $total = money_format("%.2n", $total);
```

Comment: what I did now is times 100----> 203.06*100

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called  [`money_format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_money_format.asp) that you can use. In this case the solution would be:

```
$total = money_format($_POST['dollar'].".".$_POST['cent']);
```

or even better:

```
$dollar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dollar");
$cent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cent");

//Set the local to parse monetary values correctly
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US");

//Get correct monetary value with 2 decimal place and **$** sign
$total = money_format("%.2n", $dollar.'.'.$cent);
```

Hope that helps.
Good luck!